# Possible logic error in second "if" statement?

Tags: c++

I don't understand the use of the second "if" statement here. How can "Tptr" be 0 if it's already testing for a "newcapacity" greater than zero? Could some other number as "newcapacity" make "Tptr" zero?

```
template <typename T>
T* Vector<T>::NewArray(size_t newcapacity)
// safe memory allocator
{
   T* Tptr;
   if (newcapacity > 0)
   {
      Tptr = new(std::nothrow) T [newcapacity];
      if (Tptr == 0)
      {
         std::cerr << "** Vector error: unable to allocate memory for array!\n";
         exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
   }
   else
   {
      Tptr = 0;
   }
   return Tptr;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the error message that it's printing make the reason clear?

Comment: @Barmar: I guess that RandomPleb may have thought the error message was senseless. I've certainly come across code that checks for `null` pointers being returned from a normal, throwing, `new`. Not many texts even mention `nothrow` `new`, so I think it's understandable that the OP didn't understand the significance. As another comment points out, the C++ FAQ entry on checking for null after using `new` never mentions `nothrow` and makes a near absolute statement that you never need to check for null with the only exception being about obsolete compilers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's necessary because of this line before it:

```
Tptr = new(std::nothrow) T [newcapacity];
```

The above is a [no-throw version of `new[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/nothrow) which returns a null pointer when the allocation fails. And so the next line necessarily means that it's checking if the `new[]` allocation has failed.

```
if (Tptr == 0) // Check if allocation failed
{
   // Allocation has failed
   std::cerr << "** Vector error: unable to allocate memory for array!\n";
   exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When the machine runs out of memory and you ask it not to throw an exception it returns `nullptr` that has the value 0.

Answer (score -1):

What if new returns `NULL`. You should always null check, after using `malloc` or `new`.

Comment: @neagoegab We can handle it using std::set_new_handler?

Comment: how this cope with "You should always null check"?

Comment: @neagoegab Whenever allocating memory null check...re is there any problem in it?

Comment: @neagoegab Gone through link, still don't you think before using pointer there should be null check.

Comment: @neagoegab Code in question is also written for `ancient` compiler.

Comment: Never heard of that one